# Target first-child with css data attribute

Tags: css, custom-data-attribute, pseudo-class

I'm messing around with trying to target the first `<p>` tag in a div that has a data attribute of `data-item="8"`

So far, I've tried this:

```
[data-item="8"] p:first-child {
font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

as well as this:

```
p:first-child [data-item="8"]{
font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

and it's not picking up on the style change. Not sure if I am going about this all wrong or if I am missing something where that's not going to work.

**HTML:**

```
<div data-item="8">
  <h3>Test</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse ut aliquid perspiciatis a aliquam repellat non ipsum necessitatibus distinctio quos molestias asperiores quis eaque, laudantium ipsam nulla adipisci quo nemo!</p>
<p>Quam soluta quis doloribus, ut cum iste cumque earum aliquam ratione! Fugiat nemo animi ut corrupti tempora, omnis nulla. Culpa a quibusdam sequi quia totam dolores magni ducimus nesciunt expedita.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `p[data-item="8"]:first-child`.

Comment: What's your HTML markup?

Comment: @Bauke- Interesting, that didn't work either. I think something is going on with the editor cause I just tested this out in CodePen and it works fine. So I think something else is going on.

Comment: `[data-item="8"] p:first-of-type`

Comment: @Our_Benefactors - I added some and now I _think_ I see what the issue is...

Comment: @TemaniAfif - that was it. I didn't realize that `<h3>` would throw it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go man. Just the wrong css selector.

https://codepen.io/jackgisel/pen/dyPxrOG

```
[data-item="8"] p:first-of-type {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ah yep! I realized that _after_ the fact, lol! Thanks!